# if statement help for controling a drone

Tags: java, if-statement, controls, conditional-statements

I have a ardrone that detect a face,sends me coordinates of the face etc.

I am at the stage for drone to track the face. I have center point of face and center point of frame, by which I calculate what command do I send the drone.

But my problem is that the moment drone sees a face, it sends first command e.g. `go.left()` and it just keeps going left until it crashes.

What am I doing wrong here? Here is piece of my code

```
//if result positive on x move drone left
if(piccX - facecX > 50){
    drone.goLeft();                  
}

//if result negative on x move drone right
if(piccX - facecX < 50){
    drone.goRight();
}

//if result positiveon Y, move drone up
if(piccY - facecY > 50){
    drone.up();
}

//if result negative on Y, move drone Down
if(piccY - facecY > 50){
    drone.down();
}
```

Do I introduce sleep()? I wanted to do a while loop, but I dont think I can here. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `if(piccY - facecY > 50){` condition is used for both up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could introduce state.

```
enum Heading {
    None, Up, Down, Left, Right
}
Heading currentHeading = Heading.None;

//if result positive on x move drone left
if(piccX - facecX > 50 && currentHeading != Heading.Left){
    drone.goLeft();
    currentHeading = Heading.Left;                  
}

//if result negative on x move drone right
if(piccX - facecX < 50 && currentHeading != Heading.Right){
    drone.goRight();
    currentHeading = Heading.Right;                  
}

//if result positiveon Y, move drone up
if(piccY - facecY > 50 && currentHeading != Heading.Up){
    drone.up();
    currentHeading = Heading.Up;                  
}

//if result negative on Y, move drone Down
if(piccY - facecY > 50 && currentHeading != Heading.Down){
    drone.down();
    currentHeading = Heading.Down;                  
}
```

If that isn't enough movement in the current direction, maybe creating an array of currentHeading states can simulate ramp up or distance traveled.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with ARDrones, those functions will continuously move the drone in that direction. There should be other methods within the drone object in which you can call. I think there's one called setPosition().

Comment: the only thing as I see that would stop is drone.wait(). But I dont think this would help ;/